# Illegal argument to format sequence

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, getline

I'm trying to write a getline predicate in Prolog that will grab an entire line. I'm running into problems when trying to use sformat to append strings:

```
getline(_, Str, 10) :-
        format('NL. String: ~s\n', [Str]).

getline(_, Str, -1) :-
        format('EOF. String: ~s\n', [Str]).

getline(InStr, Str, Cd) :-
        sformat(NewString, '~s~c', [Str, Cd]),
        get_code(InStr, C),
        getline(InStr, NewString, C).

getline(InStr, Str) :-
        get_code(InStr, C),
        getline(InStr, Str, C).

test(InFile) :-
        open(InFile, read, InStr),
        getline(InStr, Line).
```

running the goal test("in.txt"). with the above gets me this error:

```
ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: format/3: Illegal argument to format sequence ~s: _G940
```

It seems like _G940 is some sort of pointer, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Now it *kinda* works (i.e. no errors), but still leaves the problem of getting the complete string back up to the caller without causing the same problem again:

```
getline(_, Strn, 10) :-
        format('NL. String: ~s\n', [Strn]).

getline(_, Strn, -1) :-
        format('EOF. String: ~s\n', [Strn]).

getline(InStrm, Strn, Cd) :-
        format(string(NewString), '~s~c', [Strn, Cd]),
        get_code(InStrm, C),
        getline(InStrm, NewString, C).

getline(InStrm) :-
        get_code(InStrm, Cd),
        getline(InStrm, '', Cd).

test(InFile) :-
        open(InFile, read, InStrm),
        getline(InStrm).
```

Comment: I'm using SWI-Prolog. 

The underscores are in the "terminal" predicates, i.e. the ones that should be called when get_code sees a newline or EOF. When that happens, it doesn't need the first argument (the input stream) anymore, because it's going to stop reading. I think. Maybe.

Comment: That's reasonable. But if, for example, `sformat` doesn't instantiate `NewString` for some reason, then you query `getline(InStr, NewString, C)` you'll get the error you see. I don't see `sformat` in SWI Prolog documentation.

Comment: It seems like it's deprecated. I replaced it with the new, but still similar method: format(string(NewString), '~s~c', [Strn, Cd]). I also renamed some variables and I'm not getting the same error anymore, so I'm going to assume that I was using a reserved word or something. Now I just have to figure out how to get the whole string back to the caller.

Comment: Cool. I don't know if any of the rest of the code you're showing uses reserved, but it is a good idea to avoid common names like `test` and `getline` since they are prime candidates.

Comment: @mtbratch Starting a variable name with an underscore just tells the top-level interpreter that you don't care about the variable bindings (which are then not printed in case of a successful query). Other than that, its a variable like any other. Thus, saying that "It was no value" is misleading. The only special naming case is the anonymous variable, which is represented by a single underscore, `_`, in that two anonymous variables in the same term stand for *different* variables. For example, the query `a(1, 2) = a(_, _)` is true.

Comment: Hey, I gave your question a little too much thought, but want to [share it anyway](https://gist.github.com/P-Seebauer/8802878). I hope that is okay, I can compose an answer out of this, but am not sure if that fits your request for "somehow returning it to the caller"

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted your code a bit so that it now (1) reads the first line from the given text file, and (2) returns the first line of that text file in a string to the caller.

```
:- use_module(library(readutil)).

test(File, String):-
  setup_call_cleanup(
    open(File, read, In),
    read_line_to_string(In, String),
    close(In)
).
```

Notice that I use library `readutil` to do part of the job

Also, I use `setup_call_cleanup/3` to make sure the stream gets closed in case reading a line fails or throws an exception.

Hope this helps!